# What is a type object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

What is the type object and when is it used? It seems like a blackbox?
Which solution A or B should be used, if a paramter can have unknown kinds of object keys?

A

```
const edit: (value: object) => void = value=> {// do something }

edit({name: "Bob", age: 11})
```

B

```
type JSONObject = { [k: string]: string | number}

const edit: (value: JSONObject ) => void = value=> {// do something }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is something you declare as a reference. In your `B` example if you run the following code:

```
const myObject:JSONObject = objFromFunction();
Object.values(myObject).map(objValue => { /* 'objValue' is of type 'string' or 'number' */ });
```

This is preferred over example A, where `objValue` would be of type `any`, which is a "black box" in the TypeScript environment.

When you are declaring a type, you're assigning a scope of potential values that can be assigned. Based on how `edit()` is used, you can setup various type strategies.

---

If you know the object will explicitly be `{name:string, age:number}` then you can declare your type as such:

```
type Person = { name:string; age:number };
```

---

If you only know that object properties may only contain a string or a number, then you would declare a type like your example, but you can use a `Record`:

```
type JSONObject = Record<string, string | number>;
```

---

Lastly, if you don't know the type contained within an object, I would recommend a slight change and use `unknown`

```
type JSONObject = Record<string, unknown>;
```

Using `object` will mark any property value as `any` which gives you no type protection. `unknown` gives you a little better type protection which I won't get into here. You should be able to find articles and Q&A about why to prefer `unknown` over `any`.